# Lowest value of two level String indexed Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this associative array, I want to get `price`'s lowest value from those arrays

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=21)
      'quantity' => int 6
      'product_id' => int 3
      'category_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'price' => float 18.73
  1 =>
    array (size=21)
      'quantity' => int 21
      'product_id' => int 6
      'category_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'price' => float 0.26
  2=>
    array (size=21)
      'quantity' => int 34
      'product_id' => int 6
      'category_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'price' => float 0.63
```

I have tried

```
foreach ($products as $key_id => $prod) {
    $lowest = $prod['price'];
    if($prod['price'] < $lowest) {
        // what to do here
    }
}
```

I want to get product with lowest price and its `product_id` too, something like

```
product_id => 6 , price => 0.26
```

Comment: First try find minimum of regular array (just array filled with numbers). Then the modification is quite easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In php >= 5.5

```
$min = min(array_column($products, 'price'));
```

In php >= 5.3(suggested by deceze)

```
$min = min(array_map(function (array $product) { return $product['price']; }, $products));
```

In php >= 5.0

```
$prices = array();

foreach ($products as $product) {
  $prices[] = $product['price'];
}

$min = min($prices);
```

**EDIT**

To find both product_id and you could use this:

```
$min        = PHP_INT_MAX;
$product_id = 0;

foreach ($products as $product) {
  if ($product['price'] < $min) {
    $product_id = $product['product_id'];
    $min        = $product['price'];
  }
}
```

[array column manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) 
[min manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) 
[array_map manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) 
[anonymous functions manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Also: `min(array_map(function (array $product) { return $product['price']; }, $products))`

Comment: @deceze added your suggestion

Comment: This works .... 

What if I want to get the product_id of that array??? for example, array in my question ... I want to get returned the array as

product_id => 6 , price => 0.26

Answer (score 2):

That's where a reduce operation is very appropriate:

```
$lowest = array_reduce($products, function ($lowest, array $product) {
    return !$lowest || $product['price'] < $lowest ? $product['price'] : $lowest;
});
```

Comment: What if I want to get the product_id of that array??? for example, array in my question ... I want to get returned the array as product_id => 6 , price => 0.26

Comment: @user `return !$lowest || $product['price'] < $lowest['price'] ? $product : $lowest`

Answer (score 0):

You should only set the lowest price if it is lower than the current lowest price.

```
// Set $low to the max value
$low = PHP_INT_MAX;
foreach ($products as $key_id => $prod) {
    // If the price is lower than the current lowest, change the lowest price
    if($prod['price'] < $lowest) {
        $low = $prod['price'];
    }
}
```